# How to write a for loop in python

Tags: python

I have a for in c++ and I want to write it in python but I don't Know how to handle the condition in the for. Can anyone help me ?

```
for (int b = (i - a) / 2; a + b <= i; b++);
```

Comment: is the [internet broken](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=python+for+loop&*)?

Comment: Just so you know, half of software engineering is not ability to program rather the ability to research and read documentation. That alone is a skill!

Comment: Given the semicolon at the end of the line, the simplest Python equivalent is `pass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminating condition `a + b <= i` is equivalent to `b <= i - a` which in turn (as Python `for` uses less than not less than or equal) would be `b < i - a + 1`.

That means in Python you could write:

```
for b in range((i - a) / 2, i - a + 1):
    ...
```

But very often you don't want to write like for like when converting from C/C++ to Python. You may be better to restructure the code entirely.

Comment: yes , that works. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly:

```
for b in range((i-a)/2,a+b-1):
    print (b)
```

And if, for some reason, you need a terminating value:

```
terminatingValue = 0
for b in range((i-a)/2,a+b-1):
    terminatingValue = b
    print (b)
```

Comment: b is defined in the for statement in the c code, it isn't defined previously, so this won't work as a translation

Comment: Updated code...

Comment: This still doesn't work: the terminating value depends on the loop index.

Comment: Updated code again.

Comment: Wow you edited this a lot while I was writing my answer!

Answer (score 0):

use `while`

```
a=something
i=something
b=(i-a)/2
while(a+b<=i):
    ###do whatever you want in the loop###
    b+=1
```

Comment: Sure, a while loop may be suitable in this situation, but you fail to answer his question of "How to write a for loop in python"

Answer (score 0):

You could use the for loop and `range()` function. Example:

```
for i in range(15):
    #code to execute 15 times
```

However, because of your code, I'd recommend using a while loop instead:

```
 i = 1 #your value for i
 b = (i-a)/2
 while a+b <= i:
     # Other code
     b+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion stems from the over-generality of **C**'s iteration construct.  Python insists that all loop parameters implicitly refer to the loop index.  For the terminating condition, solve your inequality in terms of **b**, and *without* equality: **b < i - a + 1**

Now we get the **for** loop

```
for b in range((i-a)/2, (i-a)+1):
```

One interpretation is that you have a range from 0 to i-a, and you want to deal with the upper half of that.